# How to get oauth AccessToken in classic asp

Tags: oauth-2.0, vbscript, google-api, asp-classic

I want to send email by connecting google via oauth
Below is the code present for C#

```
MailSender objMail = new MailSender();

objMail.TLS = true;

objMail.Username = "myaccount@gmail.com";

objMail.Password = "[oauth]ya29.Il-8B-88nf.......GhoNhUXKtBS-ZEQOAZ9tTWg";

...

objMail.Send();
```

For whole code please navigate to
https://www.aspemail.com/net_manual_03.html#3_5

To generate access token which is appended with "[oauth]" above, we are using

```
MailSender objMail = new MailSender();

MailSender objMail2 = objMail.GetAccessToken("GMAIL", "4/wQGBh....LtcM", false);

string AccessToken = objMail2.Username;

string RefreshToken = objMail2.Password;

int ExpiresIn = objMail2.Timeout;
```

I want to implement the same functionality in classic asp, but when i am creating object of "MailSender" in classic asp, it is throwing error that:

> Object doesn't support this property or method:
> 'objMail.GetAccessToken'

Please suggest me how can i generate access token of oauth from classic asp

Comment: Classic ASP is not ASP.Net you’re looking at the wrong [User Manual](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_05.html#5_6). You should be using ASPEmail not ASPEmail.Net.

Comment: I am using ASPEmail only in classic asp, ASPEmail.Net is just for reference purpose.

Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")

Set MailToken = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")

MailToken = = Mail.GetAccessToken("GMAIL", "4/0AY0e-g4FsxUcPZPYALVFXPdzG7nVS7XL9-_06rc2VQ_doRfAQOnfcpdLuVq1vzeU7LaXNw", false);

string AccessToken = MailToken.Username;

string RefreshToken = MailToken.Password;

Comment: Please don’t post extended code segments in the comments. Instead, use [edit] to add the code to the question.

Comment: Also, according to the [documentation](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#GetAccessToken) the `GetAccessToken()` method wasn’t introduced until version 5.5.0.1. What version are you using as I suspect this is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that the object you are using doesn’t recognise the method you are trying to call. In this situation the [official documentation](https://www.aspemail.com/manual_object.html#GetAccessToken) is the best resource.

> <sup>Quote from `GetAccessToken()`</sup>
> This method was introduced in version 5.5.0.1.

The likelihood here is you are using an older version of the ASPEmail COM component.

You can use the below code to output the version information;

```vb
<%
Dim Mail
Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender")
Call Response.Write("Version: " & Mail.Version)
%>
```

Comment: This is the version which i have - Version: 5.6.0.0 (64-bit)
on this line  Mail.GetAccessToken("GMAIL", "auth code", false); 
i am getting below arror
Persits.MailSender.4 error '800a0023'
Error opening URL. HTTP Status Code: 400.

Comment: @FaisalQamar That's a different error from what you reported in the question? Did you update the version and are now getting this error?